# MongoDB Array to normal PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I have array in my MongoDB document. When im'm printing it in PHP (`print_r($user->__next_action);`) i got

```
MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument Object
(
[storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
    (
        [text] => Sometext
    )

)
```

How do I get standard PHP array from this? I need

```
Array
(
    [text] => Sometext
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
return json_decode(json_encode(iterator_to_array($user->__next_action)), TRUE);
```

Quick workaround to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Well it’s an [ArrayObject](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/blob/master/src/Model/BSONDocument.php#L33) class so `getArrayCopy` should work.